# Using ngModel with <ion-range> throws exception

Tags: angular, ionic2

I've started creating an app with Ionic v2 and TypeScript, but I've run into this issue with `<ion-range>`. The exception thrown is: `No value accessor for ''`

My code is the same as shown on the webpage at http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/range/Range/

home.ts

```
@Page({
  templateUrl:"home.html"
})
export class HomePage {
  singleValue: number;
  constructor(private nav: NavController) {
        this.singleValue = 50;
    }
}
```

home.html

```
<ion-navbar *navbar>
  <ion-title>
    Ionic 2
  </ion-title>
</ion-navbar>

<ion-content class="has-header">
  <div padding style="text-align: center;">
    <h1>Ionic 2 Test</h1>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-range [(ngModel)]="singleValue" danger pin="true"></ion-range>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Here is a [plunker showing the error](http://embed.plnkr.co/U3PXfm53ijKNYwS6ymYE/). The error is shown when you open the console.

Some google searches recommended changing the Angular library to an un-minified version or newer build, but I do not know how to change the version of angular used with ionic. Nothing inside `package.json` seems like an obvious candidate to modify.

Comment: You use old version ionic-angular - 6. Current version 7 uses angular.RC1 but you need to wait next release. Range component wasn't released yet. https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/commits/ion-range/src/components/range. It has been created only 8 days ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As yurzui mentioned, I needed a newer release of Ionic. The error was due to the documentation being more up-to-date than the released beta. A few hours ago, beta 8 was released that solved my issue with the Range component.

http://blog.ionic.io/ionic-2-beta-8-is-live/